# Varnish has default limits for cache contents(URL + query string)'s length?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

In the varnish log with `varnishncsa`, I found that the URL + query string parts seems truncated, like:

```
$ sudo varnishncsa -F "%U%q" | awk '{print $0,length}' > uq.vlen
(... few hours later within a host has a lot of traffics)
$ cat uq.vlen | sort -srn -k 2 | head -10
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
/<opaque_path>?<opaque_long_query_strings> 254
...
```

Is there a limit on URL + query string's length of varnish content?(default as 254?) Cannot find on documentations or in my vcl file(vcl 4.0) on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only hitting the log record limit [vsl_reclen](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html?highlight=vsl_reclen#vsl-reclen)

Use `varnishadm param.set vsl_reclen X` to increase it at runtime or the `-p vsl_reclen=X` command line argument to `varnishd`.

If you need to go to particularly high values, consider to increase [vsl_buffer](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#vsl-buffer) also. If you do that, also increase [workspace_client](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#workspace-client) and [workspace_backend](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#workspace-backend) by the same amount.